# Circular Dependency: Developing Mobile API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning how to make an API right now. I've run into this problem:

`Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MobileApi::V1::GlossaryController`

Code is as follows for the erroring file:

```
MobileApi::V1::GlossaryController.class_eval do
    def index
        render text: "hi there"
    end
end
```

If you'd like to see the code, its up on Github here: https://github.com/BenMorganIO/FETA

Comment: Can you check the Github link I've placed in the question? I was writing all that in and then I thought it would be faster and simpler to push my changes up to Github for everyone to see themselves.

Comment: Its structured a bit different than the average app. I have the Rails API up. Alongside Rails is ng-app which has my client side Angular app stored within it. Uses Grunt and it compiles to the public folder where / routes to via a redirect. I hope that helps.